# Testbed of perfect graphs

Tags: perfect-graph

Is there a publicly available testbed of [perfect graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph)? Ideally, the number of vertices should be 100 or more.

Comment: Are these graphs intended to be perfect, or intended to be tested for perfection?

Comment: @AndrewD.King I suppose either could be useful, though I'm looking for graphs that are known to be perfect.

Comment: There are some classes that you can easily generate "at random", e.g. bipartite graphs, line graphs of bipartite graphs, split graphs, etc.  You can also look at minimum fill-ins of random graphs.  None of these will give you what I would consider a representative sample of perfect graphs, but they're a starting point.

Comment: there are good repositories for SAT problems but it seems no repositories even for any various graph classes.... apparently researchers just generate them.... [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) is cited as working with graphs... probably the best approach would be to generate random graphs and filter out the perfect graphs?

Comment: I don't know of such a testbed either, but Mathematica is also capable of checking for perfectness.